# Django Csv Importer integer error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the latest Django Csv Importer found here: http://django-csv-importer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Line 2 of the CSV that contains integers does not have any blank lines. They're all numbers. I went into the CSV and converted all the rows with numbers to integers, then reuploaded the file, but I still get this error:

```
line 182, in import_data
return importer.import_data(data)
File "/.../lib/python2.7/csvImporter/model.py", line 282, in import_data self.process_line(data, line, lines, line_number)
File "/.../lib/python2.7/csvImporter/model.py", line 299, in process_line
    raise CsvDataException(line_number, field_error =  e.message)

CsvDataException: Line 2: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

My model is setup as follows:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    dice = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CsvCharacterUpload(CsvDbModel):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        points = models.IntegerField()
        description = models.TextField()
        image = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
        dice = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        dbModel = Character
        delimiter = ","
        has_header = True
```

Comment: make sure theres no empty spaces in between you entries, there no empty entries, and none of your text entries actually have `,` ...

Comment: open the csv file with excel or open/libreoffice calc and see if it's displayed correctly there. also python itself already has a `csv` [library](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), which you could maybe use instead of this third-party library.

Comment: Yes, I specifically used OpenOffice to do this. Everything is fine. I really don't know what it was, so I switched the numbers to CharField(). Not really suggested, but it does work there, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

CharField, IntegerField, etc... in CSVCharacterUpload should be the ones defined in django-csv-importer, not in django.models.

ie, from csv_importer.fields import CharField, IntegerField

And I would recommend to switch to [django-adaptors](https://github.com/anthony-tresontani/django-adaptors) as django-csv-importer is no more maintained.